# How to use System.Console in UWP

Tags: c#, console, uwp

I want to use windows console in UWP. I know that there is `System.Diagnostic.Debug` but it provides me only methods to display message in windows console and I want to read from the console.

Comment: Try use the Dialog to input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Console` is not available for UWP apps. If you want to create console app, use .NET Framework or .NET Core not Universal Windows Platform. The `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class is just for debugging purposes and users don't see its output.

However there are many other ways how to get user's input in UWP app, for example [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/text-box).

Comment: So, it's impossible to use console in UWP application? :(

Comment: If you mean `System.Console` then it is not possible. But you can make UWP app look like console by setting black background etc. Or you can create classic console app and using Desktop App Converter aka Project Centennial you can then upload it to Windows Store but it will be only available for PCs.

Comment: I think that you can make a dialog that like a Console.