# C# beginner program

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio and when I try to compile the code below I get two errors;

> CS0103 The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context
>
> CS0017  C# Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

How do I fix this?

```
using System;

namespace App2
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Writeline("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only use 1 'static void Main()' in your application, please make sure that you dont have 2 of them (maybe in another class)

Comment: Try Console.WriteLine("Hello"), so it works with the Console.

Comment: @WolfgangFeneberg The compiler does not understand `Console` let alone the mis-typed `Writeline`.   _"The name 'Console' does not exist in the **current context**"_

Comment: Judging from your comment about using "Blank app" template and the namespace App2, I'm guessing you pick the "Blank App (Android)" template. Use the "Console App (.NET Framework)" template instead. If it doesn't exist, make sure you select .NET Desktop Development on installation

Comment: I don't have the option to create a console application when I create a new project so I clicked on 'Blank App'

Comment: Well, it self-explanatory then. Blank App (Android)/UWP doesn't have `Main` method by default. If you want to use `System.Console` certainly you need to use `Console Application` template.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is from "Why my code is not working" category. Your code sample will work in most cases, so everyone is trying to guess what you did and what is wrong in your situation.

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio, which options you installed? If you want to develop a Console Application you must install the .Net Desktop Development Package.

Comment: @Reniuz ? I gave my errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is caused by a typo. To correct it, change `Writeline` to `WriteLine` (with a capital letter L).

The second error is caused by the fact that you did not specify clearly which entry point the program should use. To fix this, follow these steps:

Right-click on your project in **Solution Explorer**, and open the "Properties" menu. You will see the similar page and all that you should do is explicitly select entry-point.

[image]

Comment: The first error ist not caused by a typo. The first error is caused by the fact that the Console class can not be found in the System namespace. Otherwise the compiler would have complained about the "Writeline" method not being known.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Class1` is not the only class that has a `static void Main()` method defined. Usually, when you create a console application, there's a class called "Program" that already contains a method `Main`. There should be no need to add another class.

Just modify the existing `Main` method. This should solve the second error.

The `Main` method is a bit like the [Highlander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(franchise)) of methods - there can only be one.

As for the first error: You do need to target the Windows platform to be able to use `Console`, so you need to create a Console application or a Windows Forms/WPF application or the like.

Comment: I opened a new project, clicked blank app, then added a class file am I missing some downloads or plugins?

Comment: You are right - sorry, used the wrong input field... I added to the answer to make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Thorsten Dittmar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432112/c-sharp-beginner-program/45432155#45432155), ensure you don't have a duplicate `static void Main` method,

> CS0103 The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Ensure you did not create an [Universal Windows Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) (UWP) project/Android. You can't call Console on it.

Comment: You can use Console in a Windows project as well.

Comment: not in a uwp project- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089694/how-to-use-system-console-in-uwp

Answer (score 0):

As many have suspected I fixed the error by going into the installer, modified and checked off the *.NET Desktop Development*.

It works now.